# Setting sidebar active menu item as class="active" once clicked

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a sidebar with links such as "Customers", "Projects", etc. They link to the respective page. However, I want to be able to set `<li class="active">` for whichever menu item I click on, whether it be Projects or Customers.

Here's the sidebar HTML (Ruby on Rails):

```
  <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar-offcanvas">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3></h3>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li><%= link_to 'Customer Management', customers_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Project Management', projects_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the JavaScript underneath that HTML:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#sidebar .nav-pills a').click(function() {
        $('#sidebar .nav-pills li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      });
    });
</script>
```

When I click on the "Customers" page, nothing happens. However, if I set the first `<li>` to the active class, then I can see the class="active" CSS style applied to it.

Here's the CSS behind it:

```
body,html,.row-offcanvas {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#sidebar {
  width: inherit;
  min-width: 220px;
  max-width: 220px;
  background-color:#E6E5E5;
  float: left;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
#main {
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}


/*
 * off Canvas sidebar
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    width:calc(100% + 220px);
  }
    
  .row-offcanvas-left
  {
    left: -220px;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 0;
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
}

#sidebar a:hover {
    background-color:#6699FF;
}
```

Comment: When you click the link, does it navigate to that page, or is this a single-page app?

Comment: It navigates to that page, but the sidebar still appears.

Comment: How do you expect to see the change in an entirely new document..?!! You should pass store the clicked option in `localStorate`, `cookies` or something, retrieve it in the new page's `load` and set class accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I think I misread your original question. It loads on the same page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is some JavaScript that I use to add a class to the item in the navigation that matches the current URL:

```
// Get current page and set current in nav
$(".nav>li").each(function() {
    var navItem = $(this);
    if (navItem.find("a").attr("href") == location.pathname) {
      navItem.addClass("active");
    }
});
```

That code should work almost verbatim in your page. Basically it just loops through all the `li` items in the `nav`, and if it find one having a hyperlink to the current page, it will apply a class of `active` to the list item.

Comment: Nice! This works. However, when the URL is something like /customers/whatever, it goes away. Is there a way to make it only check the first slash?